# Centred child of flexbox forced aside by padding in IE11

Tags: html, css, flexbox, internet-explorer-11

In order to centrally position an `<a>` tag inside a `<div>` and have it fill the parent entirely I am using the markup and CSS in the snippet below:

```css
.container {
    align-items: center;
    background: lightcoral;
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: flex;
    height: 100px;
    justify-content: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100px;
}

.contained {
    background: lightblue;
    padding: 100px;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <a class="contained" href="#">1</a>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <a class="contained" href="#">2</a>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <a class="contained" href="#">3</a>
    </div>
</body>
```

For the purposes of demonstration the `<div>`s have fixed sizes but ultimately they may change size slightly in different viewport sizes, hence giving the `<a>` tags large amounts of padding to ensure that they always cover the entire `<div>` whilst staying central. The colours are also only included to make it easier to see the effect.

When viewed in Chrome or Firefox (version 58.0.3029.110 [64-bit] and version 53.0 [64-bit] respectively, at time of writing) the `<a>` tags are positioned centrally, with the excess padding hidden by the parent `<div>` (you should be unable to see an red colouration, only blue). However, in IE11 the `<a>` tags are being pushed off to the right by their padding, which does not match the behaviour seen in Chrome and Firefox. Furthermore, adding `flex-direction: column` to the `.container` class causes the `<a>` tag to be pushed *down* instead of *right*, which suggests the issue is tied to `flex-direction`.

Is there a workaround for IE to make it behave in the same way as Chrome and Firefox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for the anchor to fill the parent, you just need to add `flex-grow:1`, the use flex to centre it's content:

```css
.container {
    align-items: center;
    background: lightcoral;
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;   /* add this so your grow will make it grow to 100% height */
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
}

.contained {
    background: lightblue;
    flex-grow: 1;           /* add this for 100% height */
    align-self: stretch;    /* add this for 100% width */
    
    display:flex;           /* the following is for centring your anchor content */
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <a class="contained" href="#">1</a>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <a class="contained" href="#">2</a>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <a class="contained" href="#">3</a>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it will help you

No need to add hug value of `padding` you can use `flex` to get the same and you can check in IE it's working fine and your parent `background: lightcoral;` is hide now.

Here i attached IE screenshot and it's working fine.

[image]

Use `flex` to get it

```css
.container {
  align-items: center;
  background: lightcoral;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  height: 100px;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100px;
}

.contained {
  background: lightblue;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  align-self: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <a class="contained" href="#">1</a>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <a class="contained" href="#">2</a>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <a class="contained" href="#">3</a>
</div>
```